# Google analytics.js set contentGroup dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

i have google analytics on my header, and everything is working good so far.
i am trying to make content grouping, from google analytics, to work too, and the code that i have is the next one:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
...
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures'); 
ga('send', 'pageview');
<!-- End Google Analytics -->

onLoadEvent(function (){
var scatcms = $('ul.breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a').text(); /*this code is to get my category name*/

ga('set', 'contentGroup1',"'" + scatcms + "'");
ga('send', 'pageview');
});
```

### questions:

i dont know if i need the '',
can i do like this:

```
ga('set', 'contentGroup1',"'" + scatcms + "'");
```

or like this:

```
ga('set', 'contentGroup1',scatcms);
```

or another way

i tested both options, and i get mix results in the content grouping on analytics, some categories show like:

lifestyle -> correct

NaHMundo' -> not correct, the problem is in the code, i know

(not set) -> the most common what is bad

can somebody help me with this???
thanks

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the quotes around the group name, so this would suffice:

```
ga('set', 'contentGroup1', scatcms);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

You can verify this by using a tool like GA Debugger or analysing your Network tab and checking the hit that gets sent.

Make sure you also have the content group configured through the UI.

Comment: i now have GA Debugger i confirm i can see the ga(...)
he is passing correctly, i am going to wait i see the final result
thanks for that cool extension

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ga(set, {
  page: 'contentGroup1',
  title: scatcms
});
```

See here for more info:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference#set

Comment: This would only set the page path and the page title, and not the content grouping.

Comment: right, nyeun, that was my first ideia of that piece of code.
do you have any ideas??